# Findbugs error "Load of known null value" SQL connection

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, findbugs

I have DAO class with methods getting and sending data.

I'm catching Exceptions inside SQL requests, so I need to declare connection variables outside of try parenthesis.

every method looks lookes like this:

```
public Role getRole(int roleId) {
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    Role role = null;

    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("select ROLE_ID, ROLE_TEXT from ROLES WHERE ROLE_ID = :1");
        statement.setInt(1, roleId);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        role = roleMapper.mapRow(rs, 1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    } finally {
        JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(statement);
        JdbcUtils.closeConnection(connection);
        return role;
    }
}
```

But there's problem. Finbugs giving me an error, saying:

`Load of known null value in DAO.getRole`

and

```
may fail to clean up java.sql.Statement
```

So what should I do to avoid that?

Comment: Never catch exception without handle it

Comment: In which line you get the errors?

Comment: Pls post the whole error message

Comment: My solution would be to use try-with-resources: http://pastie.org/10857728 And as Jens said, don't catch and ignore the exception. Also don't assume the query returned something, check the result of `rs.next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getRole can return null.
Furthermore:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    role = roleMapper.mapRow(rs, 1);
}
```

I prefer another notation. And the error solution unfortunately consists of either letting getRole throw an exception (best) or letting return an `Optional<Role>`

```
//public Role getRole(int roleId) throws SQLException {
public Optional<Role> getRole(int roleId) {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement =
                connection.prepareStatement(
                "select ROLE_ID, ROLE_TEXT from ROLES WHERE ROLE_ID = :1")) {
        statement.setInt(1, roleId);
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return roleMapper.mapRow(rs, 1);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) { //
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "ID: " + roleId, e); //
    }
    return Optional.empty(); //
}
```